# Help installing mysql and postgres gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm an experienced developer, but a complete Rails newb. I'm trying to install an existing app that uses the Bundler gem to encapsulate and control the application environment and, after about 3 days of fighting with it, I can't seem to get the environment put together. The bundler Gemfile specifies the use of both mysql and postgres because we develop with mysql, but test and deploy against postgres.

I'm running OS X 10.6.2 with MySQL and PostgreSQL installed via MacPorts (packages: mysql5, mysql5-server, postgresql84 and postgresql84-server). I can get the mysql gem to install (and work) fine using the following:

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem bundle -- --with-mysql-dir=/opt/local/lib/mysql5 --with-mysql-lib=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql --with-mysql-include=/opt/local/include/mysql5/mysql'`

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get PostgreSQL to install. I've tried just extending the working MySQL command above with:

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem bundle -- --with-mysql-dir=/opt/local/lib/mysql5 --with-mysql-lib=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql --with-mysql-include=/opt/local/include/mysql5/mysql -- --with-pgsql-lib=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84 --with-pgsql-include=/opt/local/include/postgresql84`

No love. I'm probably missing something obvious and simple, but I just can't see it. Anyone have any ideas? Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If I comment out the `gem "postgres"` line in the Gemfile, I can install MySQL with just this:

    sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem bundle

Everything that I try with PostgreSQL, though, still fails mightily.

Comment: Installing the system gem itself, works great: `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install postgres -- --with-pgsql-lib=/opt/local/lib/postgresql83 --with-pgsql-include=/opt/local/include/postgresql83`. I just can't seem to port those same options to the `gem bundle` command and have them work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so installing the `pg` gem instead of the `postgres` gem did the trick. I guess the former is newer? Or perhaps native. I read the reason somewhere, but can't remember where. It still requires the `ARCHFLAG`, but I was able to install the gem without the other options.